# Tomcat run time error - Deployed Spring boot war and throwing NullPointerException with StringTokenizer.init

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I installed openjdk 17 in my system and for the project I used temurin jdk1.8(downloaded directly from intellij and used, I have multiple projects with different versions so this particular project used temurin jdk1.8). I added war into the tomcat(version - 9.0.85) deployment section in intellij but when I try to run the tomcat server, it's throwing an error i.e NPE in StringTokenizer.init(StringTokenizer.java:199), error details are as follows,

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.management.ObjectName.quote(ObjectName.java:1833)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createObjectName(MBeanUtils.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createMBean(MBeanUtils.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.initInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4688)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1791)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:453)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:407)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
16-Feb-2024 18:15:24.909 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\IntellIJ\software\apache-tomcat-9.0.85-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.85\webapps\manager]
16-Feb-2024 18:15:24.932 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.initInternal Failed to create MBean for naming resource [null]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.management.ObjectName.quote(ObjectName.java:1833)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createObjectName(MBeanUtils.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createMBean(MBeanUtils.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.initInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4688)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1941)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1096)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1668)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1283)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
16-Feb-2024 18:15:25.022 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [D:\IntellIJ\software\apache-tomcat-9.0.85-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.85\webapps\manager]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1941)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1096)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1668)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1283)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/manager]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 27 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
        at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createSubcontexts(NamingContextListener.java:1222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:975)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:536)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4820)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        ... 28 more
```

It seems to be not a project set up or deployment issue, it looks like some issue with java.
Let me know if anyone faced similar issu

Comment: you should show the actual code and the complete stacktrace. Also, you shouldn't write new code using StringTokenizer. Already in Java 8, the documentation for StringTokenizer said: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Is this Spring MVC, which does need an app server, or Spring Boot, which does not? Spring Boot applications are Java applications.

Comment: @Stultuske I didn't use any StringTokenizer class in the code.

Comment: @nitind I developed application with Spring MVC and deployed war into the tomcat server through intellij it's local server.

Comment: Are you configuring anything with JNDI? Can you append your deployment descriptor to the question?

Comment: @AnilNivargi did you read the title of your question? Did you read what you mentioned about the StackTrace? "and throwing NullPointerException with StringTokenizer.init" somewhere it is being used. If you didn't code it manually, you are using some very out of date libraries